Solana libraries in kotlin give unresolved reference
import com.solana.rpc.SolanaRpcClient
import com.solana.networking.KtorNetworkDriver

I have tried to import these libraries but they both give unresolved reference error. First one on rpc and the second one on KtorNetworkDriver. I have followed this documentation https://docs.solanamobile.com/android-native/rpc-requests hence added this dependancy and synced; also tried cleaning and rebuilding but the error persists. I literally cannot find any information on this since it's a niche topic.
dependencies {
    implementation("com.solanamobile:rpc-core:0.2.6")
} 


Doesn't solve your original question, but you can do it with sol4k as well. It uses minimum dependencies and shouldn't bring any issues importing.
implementation 'org.sol4k:sol4k:0.5.4'

Find the details in the documentation.

In the end I just manually imported the files myself. Could you please take a look at another issue im facing? It seems like you could know whats wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79006586/mobilewalletadapter-transact-doesnt-return-a-result-using-phantom-wallet

@JurajMarincic unfortunately I haven't tried the wallet adapter library
