MobileWalletAdapter.transact() doesn't return a result using Phantom Wallet
I'm trying to make a Solana application with Kotlin and communicate with a smart contract that I deployed with Anchor framework. However, every time I try to connect the wallet the app crashes. It successfully redirects me to Phantom Wallet app and asks me for connection but when I click "Connect" in the Phantom app it brings me back to my Kotlin app and doesn't do anything while it should pop up a window again and ask for a transaction approval. The logs show that the function does not return anything. The way I'm handling sender is getting the reference in the MainActivity and passing it to the screen. In that screen I have a button where this function triggers onClick and I pass the sender as an argument.
suspend fun onBuyTicket(ticket: Ticket, sender: ActivityResultSender) {
Log.d("TicketDApp", "Starting to buy ticket: ${ticket.id}")

val programId = SolanaPublicKey.from("F75bTjnaqScc9VZz6p5dKxFyxdBNQ48g7UURVZCwTSyH")

val solanaUri = Uri.parse("https://juraj_diplomski.com")
val iconUri = Uri.parse("favicon.ico")
val identityName = "juraj_diplomski"

val walletAdapter = MobileWalletAdapter(
    connectionIdentity = ConnectionIdentity(
        identityUri = solanaUri,
        iconUri = iconUri,
        identityName = identityName
    ),
    scenarioProvider = AssociationScenarioProvider()
)

Log.d("TicketDApp", "Wallet adapter initialized")

walletAdapter.transact(sender) { authResult ->
    Log.d("TicketDApp", "Transaction authorization result: $authResult")

This is how my logcat looks. Note that the WebSocket error is only showing while the wallet app is still starting or I'm in the process of choosing which wallet app to use.
Logcat part one
Logcat part two
